# Call a list of functions with random parameters

Tags: python, function, loops, random

How can I call a set of functions using random arguments.

```
import random

def sum_3 (a):
    return (sum(a) + 3)
def sum_2 (b):
    return (sum(b) + 2)

# Call the functions 
functions = [sum_3, sum_2]
# Using random arguments
random.sample(range(1, 100000), 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over your functions and call them with the sample.

```
>>> the_sample = random.sample(range(1, 100000), 5)
>>> the_sample
>>> [6163, 38513, 35085, 4876, 27506]
>>>
>>> for func in functions:
...:    print(func(the_sample))
...:    
112146
112145
```

Building a list of the results:

```
>>> [func(the_sample) for func in functions]
>>> [112146, 112145]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `functions` is a list of functions:

```
import random
# Call your function like this:
random.choice(functions)(a)
```

Use `np.random.choice` if you prefer to use `numpy` (which I do since it's more of a default math library)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how many times you want to call it. One approach is as follows:

```
import random

def sum_3 (a):
    print('calling sum3 with', a)
    return (sum(a) + 3)

def sum_2 (b):
    print('calling sum2 with', b)
    return (sum(b) + 2)

functions = [sum_3, sum_2]
for i in range(3): # call each function 3 times
    for func in functions:
        print(func(random.sample(range(1, 100000), random.randint(2, 6))))
```

#### Output

```
calling sum3 with [76385, 37776, 19464]
133628
calling sum2 with [21520, 97936, 44610]
164068
calling sum3 with [1184, 4786]
5973
calling sum2 with [2680, 36487, 24265, 39569, 18331]
121334
calling sum3 with [87777, 81241, 95238, 58267, 3434, 85015]
410975
calling sum2 with [5020, 68999, 50868, 17544]
142433
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define a generic function which allows me to choose and pre-define which functions I will use, then apply the chosen ones with parameters. You can consider this is a two steps approach:

1. Compile the functions that you will need into an object.
2. Apply functions in the compiled object to parameters.

So, instead of putting functions in a list as you did in the question, you compile them in an object with another function. It works for the case of multiple functions as well as single function, thus is very generic.

```
import random

def sum_3 (a):
    return (sum(a) + 3)
def sum_2 (b):
    return (sum(b) + 2)

parameters = random.sample(range(1, 100000),5)

# generic function to apply functions on parameters
def compile(*fs): return lambda x: map(lambda f: f(x), fs)

# choose the functions you want to apply
dosum3and2 = compile(sum_3,sum_2)
dosum2only = compile(sum_2)

# apply the defined functions to parameters
print(list(dosum3and2(parameters)))
print(list(dosum2only(parameters)))
# output =>
# [294334, 294333]
# [294333]
```

When you have many functions `sum_1`, `sum_2`, `sum_3`, ..., `sum_n`, you compile them first then apply to parameters like

```
# compile the chosen functions
# which looks very similar as what you did with list (functions = [sum_3, sum_2]).
functions = compile(sum_1,sum_2,sum_3,...,sum_n)
# apply to parameters
functions(parameters)
```